# MediaPlayer doesn't work

Tags: android

I created a simple application.
In my main activity class i use this to play a sound when a button is clicked

```
MediaPlayer buttonSound = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.drawable.button_sound); 

public void onClick(View arg0){
                buttonSound.start();
                             }
```

In my main activity class i have a service that start a background music

```
 Intent svc=new Intent(this, BackgroundSoundService.class);
 startService(svc);
```

the problem is that if i dont' start the service `startService(svc);` the button sound don't play!
Why? They are two differents things!

Answer (score 1):

here

```
MediaPlayer buttonSound = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.drawable.button_sound); 
                                                    //^^^^^^^
```

don't put your audio or video files in drawable folder . move it to res/raw folder and Create media instance as:

```
MediaPlayer buttonSound = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.button_sound);
```

Answer (score 0):

Create a raw folder in `/res/raw` and store your audio or sound file in this folder. from this folder call your audio file.

like this

```
MediaPlayer soundBtn = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.sound_btn);
```

Comment: Sorry, actually it works the way I did, maybe there was another error that prevent it to work proberly.
Besides raw folder, can i create new folder to store file in?

Comment: according to android docs all media file are stored in raw folder. for more detail go to android site http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/available-resources.html

Comment: this site ll give more enough information about resource http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/providing-resources.html